# How do I get a Bitmap from the TWebImageControl component?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, tms, tms-web-core

During design-time in my TMS Web Core Website, I added a `.png` image to the `TWebImageControl` component using the `Picture` property:

[image: Delphi TWebImageControl Component in TMS Web Core]

But now in run-time, I want to get the Bitmap of the image with code. I tried `WebImageControl2.Bitmap` and `WebImageControl2.Picture.Bitmap`, but there isn't a `Bitmap` method or property to get it from. It says:

> [Error] uMain_web.pas(277): identifier not found "Bitmap"

So, how can I get a bitmap from the `TWebImageControl` component?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're in a **web** scope - bitmaps rarily make sense there, and you're not in your Windows GUI anymore where the lowest common denominator is a bitmap. What's your actual problem?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but you can use WebImageControl2.Base64Image.  To convert to a picture you can use set a TGraphic.URL to the Base64 variable.   Keep in mind, the Base64Image is a png.  I usually send the Base64 to the back end for processing to save to a folder.

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe this requires a different question then, but basically what I'm doing on one of my FMX apps is I get the `TBitmap` from the image component and then I can use that Bitmap to do various things on it such as transformations (Rotate, Flip, Change Colors, etc.). I do all of this via the `TBitmap` that I get from the Image component.

Comment: So `TBitmap` is simply something that doesn't exist in TMS Web Core at all?

Comment: Surprise: [CSS knows rotation already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) and also other transformations. Reconsider your bitmap approach.

Comment: Whatever you can do with javascript you can do with WebCore.  You just need to change your thinking in that regard.   Javascript isn't aware of TBitmap.

Comment: @AmigoJack I know you can do rotations and other things using CSS already, but I always try to do as much as I can using only Delphi and not any HTML, CSS, or JS.

Comment: `TBitmap` does exist somewhere in TMS Web Core, because they're talking about `TBitmap` in this link: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=675